# Are these grocery store oyster mushrooms OK to eat?

Tags: mushrooms

I bought these at the grocery two days ago. They have been in the fridge. They are firm. The white fungus in the gills is firm too. No bad smell. Can I cook and eat?[image]
[image]

Comment: My first thought is, given the ways mushrooms are cultivated, the most likely fungus to be in the gills of your oyster mushrooms is other oyster mushrooms, since direct access to the spores is pretty likely.  I have no proof, though, and while I probably would risk it (given the lack of soft spots or bad smells), I'm not sure I can recommend someone else take that risk without more information than I have.  Maybe if you go back to the store and see if these are common on other oyster mushrooms and/or check with an employee that they're good (or at least salable)?

Comment: they're store bought mushrooms, they have no immune systems. expect that stuff to happen to them.

Answer (score 2):

They're likely mycelium rather than other moulds, its not uncommon for certain varieties of stored mushrooms to start producing mycelia (the root system of mushrooms generally). According to this link, mould on mushrooms is more likely to be green,black or brown

http://www.gourmetmushroomsinc.com/fresh-restaurants-faq.htm